# Nutch 1.2 Solr 3.6 integration issue

Tags: solr, nutch

I have crawled a site successfully using NUTCH 1.2 .Now I want to integrate this with solr 3.6 . Problem is when I am issuing command
`$ bin/nutch solrindex //localhost:8080/solr/ crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*` an error occurs

```
 SolrIndexer: starting at 2013-07-08 14:52:27
java.io.IOException: Job failed!
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Here is my nutch log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version (expected 2, but 60) or the data in not in 'javabin' format
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:99)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BinaryResponseParser.processResponse(BinaryResponseParser.java:41)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:469)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:249)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.close(SolrWriter.java:75)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216)
2013-07-08 15:17:39,539 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job f
```

Comment: can you check the solr and nutch logs where the error would be mentioned in details

Comment: @Jayendra hey.. Please can you tell me where to find those logs

Comment: nutch uses hadoop underlying so check in the nucth folder for hadoop.log file.

Comment: @Jayendra Thanx bro . I have edited my question and added hadoop.log file . Please go through it and guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly the javabin incompatiblity between the Solrj version jars used by Nutch and the Solr 3.6 which you are trying to integrate.

You would need to update the Solrj jars and regenerate the jobs.

Follow the steps as mentioned in the [forum](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Nutch-1-2-Solr-3-1-0-solrindex-Job-failed-td2838580.html).